# Stored Procedure: nested group by with case when's and other strangeness

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Please, consider this `stored procedure` that I recently inherited. (It uses `dynamic SQL` so, this is the **actual** `SQL` it runs after it gets built.)

I am quite baffled as to it's structure and how it actually works but I need to fix a semantic bug. It is selecting, from what looks like, two derived tables. But the `JOINS` and `GROUP BY`'s are mangled, IMO, in the second table, '`C`'. I cannot follow it. Perhaps some concepts elude me, such as joining on a derived table the way it does for table '`C`'. And the `group by` even has a `Case When` along with a `JOIN` inside it. I'm quite puzzled.

What I really need explained is the lower part where it's joining on table 'C' and then following, what appears to be nested `Group By`'s with `Case When`'s

EDIT: The semantic error is: for param @OrderType, it will either give one of two set of results or both totaled up, and the total doesn't match the sum of the two results together. eg: @OrderType = 4 gives 1000, @OrderType = 0 gives 1000, @OrderType = -1 (total) gives 1234... which doesn't add up.

Here it is:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
SELECT COUNT(C.BaseOrderNo) AS [Orders Imported], 
    SUM(CASE WHEN C.TotalOrderQty = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Single Qty Orders], 
    CAST(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN C.TotalOrderQty = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUMERIC) / COUNT(C.TotalOrderQty) * 100 AS DECIMAL(19,2)) AS [% Single Qty], 
    SUM(CASE WHEN C.TotalOrderQty > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Multi-Qty Orders], 
    CAST(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN C.TotalOrderQty > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUMERIC) / COUNT(C.TotalOrderQty) * 100 AS DECIMAL(19,2)) AS [% Multi-Qty], 
    SUM(C.TotalOrderQty) AS [Total Qty], 
    AVG(C.TotalOrderQty) AS [Average Item Qty], 
    S.NumOrdersSplit AS [Num Orders Split], 
    CAST(CAST(S.NumOrdersSplit AS NUMERIC) / COUNT(C.BaseOrderNo)* 100 AS DECIMAL(19,2)) AS [% Split Orders], 
    SUM(CASE WHEN O.NumSplits = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [1X Split], 
    SUM(CASE WHEN O.NumSplits = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [2X Split], 
    SUM(CASE WHEN O.NumSplits = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [3X Split], 
    SUM(CASE WHEN O.NumSplits >= 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [>=4X Split] 
    /*SUM(CASE WHEN C.TotalLines > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Multi-Line Orders], SUM(C.TotalLines) AS [Num Lines], AVG(CAST(C.TotalLines AS NUMERIC)) AS [Avg Num Lines]*/ 
FROM 
(  
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',OA.OrderNo)>0 THEN LEFT(OA.OrderNo,CHARINDEX('-',OA.OrderNo)-1) ELSE OA.OrderNo END) AS NumOrdersSplit 
FROM OrdersViewWImport O  WITH (NOLOCK) 
    INNER JOIN OrderActions OA WITH (NOLOCK) 
        ON OA.OrderNo=O.OrderNo 
    left outer join VendorBuyers BORD WITH (NOLOCK) 
        on BORD.Buyer = 'admin' 
        and BORD.Usage = 10000 
        and BORD.VendorNo = O.VendorNo 
        and BORD.fgSpecialPO = O.fgSpecialPO 
    where 
        case when BORD.EMailId is null then case when IsNull(BORD.Type, 0) = 1 then 1 when O.fgSpecialPO in (0, 2, 4) then 1 when O.fgSpecialPO in (1, 3, 5) then 1 end else 0 end = 1 
        AND O.fgSpecialPO IN (4) 
        AND O.ImportDate >= '2015-12-20' 
        AND O.ImportDate < '2015-12-26' 
        AND OA.Type=56
    ) S, 
    ( -- FROM HERE DOWN IS THE CONFUSION
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',OI.OrderNo)>0 THEN LEFT(OI.OrderNo,CHARINDEX('-',OI.OrderNo)-1) ELSE OI.OrderNo END AS BaseOrderNo, 
        SUM(OI.Quantity) AS TotalOrderQty, 
        COUNT(1) AS TotalLines 
    FROM 
        OrderItems OI WITH (NOLOCK) 
    GROUP BY 
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',OI.OrderNo)>0 THEN LEFT(OI.OrderNo,CHARINDEX('-',OI.OrderNo)-1) ELSE OI.OrderNo END) C 
    INNER JOIN 
        ( SELECT 
            CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',O.OrderNo)>0 THEN LEFT(O.OrderNo,CHARINDEX('-',O.OrderNo)-1) ELSE O.OrderNo END AS BaseOrderNo, 
            COUNT(1) AS NumSplits, 
            O.ImportDate, 
            'Default' AS VendorNo, 
            O.fgSpecialPO 
        FROM OrdersViewWImport O WITH (NOLOCK) GROUP BY CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',O.OrderNo)>0 THEN LEFT(O.OrderNo,CHARINDEX('-',O.OrderNo)-1) ELSE O.OrderNo END, 
        O.ImportDate, 
        O.fgSpecialPO) O ON O.BaseOrderNo=C.BaseOrderNo 
    inner join
        (select COUNT(1) as [PerOrder], 
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',oa.OrderNo)>0 THEN LEFT(oa.OrderNo,CHARINDEX('-',oa.OrderNo)-1) ELSE oa.OrderNo END as BaseOrderNo 
    from OrderActions as oa WITH (NOLOCK) 
    where Type = 36  
    GROUP BY 
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',oa.OrderNo)>0 THEN LEFT(oa.OrderNo,CHARINDEX('-',oa.OrderNo)-1) ELSE oa.OrderNo END ) cnt 
        on cnt.BaseOrderNo = C.BaseOrderNo 
        left outer join VendorBuyers BORD WITH (NOLOCK) on BORD.Buyer = 'admin' and BORD.Usage = 10000 and BORD.VendorNo = O.VendorNo and BORD.fgSpecialPO = O.fgSpecialPO 
        where case when BORD.EMailId is null then 
                case when IsNull(BORD.Type, 0) = 1 then 1 
                    when O.fgSpecialPO in (0, 2, 4) then 1 
                    when O.fgSpecialPO in (1, 3, 5) then 1 end 
                    else 0 end = 1 
            AND O.fgSpecialPO IN (4) 
            AND O.ImportDate >= '2015-12-20' 
            AND O.ImportDate < '2015-12-26' 
        GROUP BY S.NumOrdersSplit 
        ORDER BY [Orders Imported] 

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
```

for those who asked, here's the actual `stored procedure` with all the **DYNAMIC SQL**:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[XYZ]
@GetDetails integer,
@VendorAlias nvarchar(30), 
@VendorNo nvarchar(10),
@OrderType integer,
@MergeOrderTypes integer,
@FromDate nvarchar(30) = '',
@ToDate nvarchar(30) = '',
@Sort nvarchar(100),
@PageNum integer,
@RecordsPerPage integer,
@Culture as nvarchar(10),
@TotalRecords integer output
as
SET NOCOUNT ON

if @GetDetails = 1
if Upper(Left(@Culture,2)) = 'DE'
begin
select  N'SFS Multi-Anzahl & Split-Bestellungen'                                as ReportName
    ,   '[Orders Imported]'                                                     as DefaultSort
    ,   N'Statistik über Bestellungen vor Teilung, basierend auf Import-Datum'  as Description
    ,   2                                                                       AS DateRange
end
else
begin
select 
    N'SFS Multi-Qty & Split Order Stats (2142)' as ReportName, 
    '[Orders Imported]' as DefaultSort,
    N'Pre-Split order statistics based on import date.' as Description,
    2 AS DateRange
end 
else
 begin
declare @dsLog as integer, @poLog as integer, @OrderModify as integer, @IsAdmin as bit, @sql as nvarchar(4000), @orderBuyerLogic nvarchar(4000)

select @dsLog = count(1) from VendorBuyers WITH (NOLOCK) where Buyer = @VendorAlias and Usage = 10000 and Type = 1 and fgSpecialPO = 0
select @poLog = count(1) from VendorBuyers WITH (NOLOCK) where Buyer = @VendorAlias and Usage = 10000 and Type = 1 and fgSpecialPO = 1
select @OrderModify = OrderModify from Security WITH (NOLOCK) where Template in (select Template from Logons WITH (NOLOCK) where VendorAlias = @VendorAlias)
select @IsAdmin = IsAdmin from Vendors VTest WITH (NOLOCK) where VTest.VendorNo = @VendorNo

if @IsAdmin = 1
    begin
        set @orderBuyerLogic =  
            'left outer join VendorBuyers BORD WITH (NOLOCK) on BORD.Buyer = ''' + @VendorAlias + ''' and BORD.Usage = 10000 and BORD.VendorNo = O.VendorNo ' + 
            'and BORD.fgSpecialPO = O.fgSpecialPO where ' +
            'case when BORD.EMailId is null then ' +
                'case ' +
                'when IsNull(BORD.Type, 0) = 1 then 1 '
        set @orderBuyerLogic = @orderBuyerLogic + 
                'when O.fgSpecialPO in (0, 2, 4) then '
        If @dsLog = 0
            set @orderBuyerLogic = @orderBuyerLogic + '1 '
        Else
            set @orderBuyerLogic = @orderBuyerLogic + '0 '
        set @orderBuyerLogic = @orderBuyerLogic + 
                'when O.fgSpecialPO in (1, 3, 5) then '
        If @poLog = 0
            set @orderBuyerLogic = @orderBuyerLogic + '1 '
        Else
            set @orderBuyerLogic = @orderBuyerLogic + '0 '
        set @orderBuyerLogic = @orderBuyerLogic +
                'end ' +
            'else 0 ' +
            'end = 1 '
    end 

if @IsAdmin <> 1
    set @orderBuyerLogic = N'WHERE O.VendorNo = ''' + @VendorNo + ''' '

if @OrderType <> -1 
begin
    set @orderBuyerLogic = @orderBuyerLogic + N'AND O.fgSpecialPO IN (' + cast(@OrderType as nvarchar)
    if (@MergeOrderTypes & 1) = 1 
        set @orderBuyerLogic = @orderBuyerLogic + N',0'
    if (@MergeOrderTypes & 2) = 2 
        set @orderBuyerLogic = @orderBuyerLogic + N',1'
    if (@MergeOrderTypes & 4) = 4 
        set @orderBuyerLogic = @orderBuyerLogic + N',2'
    if (@MergeOrderTypes & 8) = 8 
        set @orderBuyerLogic = @orderBuyerLogic + N',3'
    if (@MergeOrderTypes & 16) = 16 
        set @orderBuyerLogic = @orderBuyerLogic + N',4'
    if (@MergeOrderTypes & 32) = 32
        set @orderBuyerLogic = @orderBuyerLogic + N',5'
    set @orderBuyerLogic = @orderBuyerLogic + N') '
end

set @sql = N'SELECT COUNT(C.BaseOrderNo) AS [Orders Imported], ' +
                N'SUM(CASE WHEN C.TotalOrderQty = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Single Qty Orders], ' +
                N'CAST(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN C.TotalOrderQty = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUMERIC) / COUNT(C.TotalOrderQty) * 100 AS DECIMAL(19,2)) AS [% Single Qty], ' +
                N'SUM(CASE WHEN C.TotalOrderQty > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Multi-Qty Orders], ' +
                N'CAST(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN C.TotalOrderQty > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUMERIC) / COUNT(C.TotalOrderQty) * 100 AS DECIMAL(19,2)) AS [% Multi-Qty], ' +
                N'SUM(C.TotalOrderQty) AS [Total Qty], ' +
                N'AVG(C.TotalOrderQty) AS [Average Item Qty], ' +
                N'S.NumOrdersSplit AS [Num Orders Split], ' +
                N'CAST(CAST(S.NumOrdersSplit AS NUMERIC) / COUNT(C.BaseOrderNo)* 100 AS DECIMAL(19,2)) AS [% Split Orders], ' +

                N'SUM(CASE WHEN O.NumSplits = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [1X Split], ' +
                N'SUM(CASE WHEN O.NumSplits = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [2X Split], ' +
                N'SUM(CASE WHEN O.NumSplits = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [3X Split], ' +
                N'SUM(CASE WHEN O.NumSplits >= 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [>=4X Split] ' +
                N'/*SUM(CASE WHEN C.TotalLines > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Multi-Line Orders], ' +
                N'SUM(C.TotalLines) AS [Num Lines], ' +
                N'AVG(CAST(C.TotalLines AS NUMERIC)) AS [Avg Num Lines]*/ ' +
            N'FROM (  ' +
                N'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(''-'',OA.OrderNo)>0 THEN LEFT(OA.OrderNo,CHARINDEX(''-'',OA.OrderNo)-1) ELSE OA.OrderNo END) AS NumOrdersSplit ' +
                N'FROM OrdersViewWImport O  WITH (NOLOCK) ' +
                N'INNER JOIN OrderActions OA WITH (NOLOCK) ON OA.OrderNo=O.OrderNo ' + @orderBuyerLogic

If @FromDate <> ''
    set @sql = @sql + N'AND O.ImportDate >= ''' + @FromDate + ''' AND O.ImportDate < ''' + @ToDate + ''' '

set @sql = @sql + N'AND OA.Type=56) S, ' +
                N'( ' +
                N'SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(''-'',OI.OrderNo)>0 THEN LEFT(OI.OrderNo,CHARINDEX(''-'',OI.OrderNo)-1) ELSE OI.OrderNo END AS BaseOrderNo, SUM(OI.Quantity) AS TotalOrderQty, COUNT(1) AS TotalLines ' +
                N'FROM OrderItems OI WITH (NOLOCK) ' +
                N'GROUP BY CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(''-'',OI.OrderNo)>0 THEN LEFT(OI.OrderNo,CHARINDEX(''-'',OI.OrderNo)-1) ELSE OI.OrderNo END) C ' +
            N'INNER JOIN ( ' +
                    N'SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(''-'',O.OrderNo)>0 THEN LEFT(O.OrderNo,CHARINDEX(''-'',O.OrderNo)-1) ELSE O.OrderNo END AS BaseOrderNo, COUNT(1) AS NumSplits, O.ImportDate, ''Default'' AS VendorNo, O.fgSpecialPO ' +
                    N'FROM OrdersViewWImport O WITH (NOLOCK) ' +
                    N'GROUP BY CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(''-'',O.OrderNo)>0 THEN LEFT(O.OrderNo,CHARINDEX(''-'',O.OrderNo)-1) ELSE O.OrderNo END, O.ImportDate, O.fgSpecialPO) ' + 
                N'O ON O.BaseOrderNo=C.BaseOrderNo ' + 
            N'inner join(select COUNT(1) as [PerOrder], CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(''-'',oa.OrderNo)>0 THEN LEFT(oa.OrderNo,CHARINDEX(''-'',oa.OrderNo)-1) ELSE oa.OrderNo END as BaseOrderNo ' +
                    N'from OrderActions as oa WITH (NOLOCK) ' +
                    N'where Type = 36  ' +
                    N'GROUP BY CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(''-'',oa.OrderNo)>0 THEN LEFT(oa.OrderNo,CHARINDEX(''-'',oa.OrderNo)-1) ELSE oa.OrderNo END ' +
                    N') cnt on cnt.BaseOrderNo = C.BaseOrderNo ' + @orderBuyerLogic 


If @FromDate <> ''
    set @sql = @sql + N'AND O.ImportDate >= ''' + @FromDate + ''' AND O.ImportDate < ''' + @ToDate + ''' '

set @sql = @sql + N'GROUP BY S.NumOrdersSplit ORDER BY '
if rTrim(@Sort) = '' 
    set @sql = @sql + N'[Orders Imported] '
else
    set @sql = @sql + @Sort

SELECT 3 AS [Orders Imported], 3 AS [Single Qty Orders], 3 AS [% Single Qty], 3 AS [Multi-Qty Orders], 3 AS [% Multi-Qty],
        3 AS [Total Qty], 3 AS [Average Item Qty], 3 AS [Num Orders Split], 3 AS [% Split Orders], 3 AS [1X Split], 3 AS [2X Split], 3 AS [3X Split],
        3 AS [>=4X Split]
        --3 AS [Multi-Line Orders], 3 AS [Num Lines], 3 AS [Avg Num Lines]

if @GetDetails = -1
begin
    set @sql = N'SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED' + char(13) + @sql + char(13) + N'SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED'

    select @sQL

    EXEC(@sql)
end
else
begin
    declare @inTable table (
        [i] integer identity (1, 1) not null,
        [Orders Imported] int not null,
        [Single Qty Orders] int not null,
        [% Single Qty] decimal (19, 2) not null,
        [Multi-Qty Orders] int not null,
        [% Multi-Qty] decimal (19, 2) not null,
        [Total Qty] decimal (19, 0) not null,
        [Average Item Qty] decimal (19, 2) not null,
        [Num Orders Split] int not null,
        [% Split Orders] decimal (19, 2) not null,

        [1X Split] int not null,
        [2X Split] int not null,
        [3X Split] int not null,
        [>=4X Split] int not null

--          [Multi-Line Orders] int not null,
--          [Num Lines] int not null,
--          [Avg Num Lines] decimal (19, 2) not null
    )

    declare @OrdersImported int,@SingleQtyOrders int,@PctSingleQty decimal (19, 2),@MultiQtyOrders int,
            @PctMultiQty decimal (19, 2),@TotalQty decimal (19, 0),@AverageItemQty decimal (19, 2),
            @NumOrdersSplit int, @PctSplitOrders decimal (19, 2), @avgapo decimal(19,2), @1xsplit int, @2XSplit int, @3XSplit int, @GT4XSplit int
            --@MultiLineOrders int,@NumLines int,@AvgNumLines decimal (19, 2)

    IF @PageNum < 1
        SET @PageNum = 1
    IF @RecordsPerPage < 15
        SET @RecordsPerPage = 15
    DECLARE @i int
    SET @TotalRecords = (@PageNum - 1) * @RecordsPerPage
    SET @i = @TotalRecords + 1
    SET @sql = N'SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED' + char(13) + N'DECLARE cc CURSOR KEYSET READ_ONLY FOR ' + @sql + char(13) + N'SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED'

    --print @sql;

    exec(@Sql)
    OPEN cc
    SET @TotalRecords = @@CURSOR_ROWS
    IF @i > 1
    BEGIN
        WHILE @i > @TotalRecords AND @i > 0
            SET @i = @i - @RecordsPerPage
        IF @i < 1
            SET @i = 1
    END
    FETCH ABSOLUTE @i FROM cc INTO @OrdersImported,@SingleQtyOrders,@PctSingleQty,@MultiQtyOrders,@PctMultiQty,@TotalQty,@AverageItemQty,@NumOrdersSplit,@PctSplitOrders,@1XSplit,@2XSplit,@3XSplit,@GT4XSplit
    WHILE @RecordsPerPage > 0 AND @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @RecordsPerPage = @RecordsPerPage - 1
        INSERT INTO @inTable ([Orders Imported],[Single Qty Orders],[% Single Qty],[Multi-Qty Orders],[% Multi-Qty],[Total Qty],[Average Item Qty],[Num Orders Split],[% Split Orders],[1X Split],[2X Split],[3X Split],[>=4X Split]) VALUES 
            (@OrdersImported,@SingleQtyOrders,@PctSingleQty,@MultiQtyOrders,@PctMultiQty,@TotalQty,@AverageItemQty,@NumOrdersSplit,@PctSplitOrders,@1XSplit,@2XSplit,@3XSplit,@GT4XSplit)
        FETCH NEXT FROM cc INTO @OrdersImported,@SingleQtyOrders,@PctSingleQty,@MultiQtyOrders,@PctMultiQty,@TotalQty,@AverageItemQty,@NumOrdersSplit,@PctSplitOrders,@1XSplit,@2XSplit,@3XSplit,@GT4XSplit
    END
    CLOSE cc
    DEALLOCATE cc
    if Upper(Left(@Culture,2)) = 'DE'
    Begin
        SELECT  [Orders Imported]   as [Orders Imported]
            ,   [Single Qty Orders] as [Single Qty Orders]
            ,   [% Single Qty]      as [% Single Qty]
            ,   [Multi-Qty Orders]  as [Multi-Qty Orders]
            ,   [% Multi-Qty]       as [% Multi-Qty]
            ,   [Total Qty]         as [Total Qty]
            ,   [Average Item Qty]  as [Average Item Qty]
            ,   [Num Orders Split]  as [Num Orders Split]
            ,   [% Split Orders]    as [% Split Orders]
            ,   [1X Split]          as [1X Split]
            ,   [2X Split]          as [2X Split]
            ,   [3X Split]          as [3X Split]
            ,   [>=4X Split]        as [>=4X Split] 
        FROM 
            @inTable 
        ORDER BY 
            i 
    end
else
    SELECT [Orders Imported],[Single Qty Orders],[% Single Qty],[Multi-Qty Orders],[% Multi-Qty],[Total Qty],[Average Item Qty],[Num Orders Split],[% Split Orders],[1X Split],[2X Split],[3X Split],[>=4X Split] FROM @inTable ORDER BY i
end
end
```

Comment: no, in the stored procedure itself, based on conditionals, it builds the sql.

Comment: @Hogan, it's dynamic sql. I'll post the SP itself so you can see.

Comment: I re-posted the full SP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say the problem is with @OrderType.  It is used in just one place:

```
if @OrderType <> -1 
begin
    set @orderBuyerLogic = @orderBuyerLogic + N'AND O.fgSpecialPO IN (' + cast(@OrderType as nvarchar)
    if (@MergeOrderTypes & 1) = 1 
        set @orderBuyerLogic = @orderBuyerLogic + N',0'
    if (@MergeOrderTypes & 2) = 2 
        set @orderBuyerLogic = @orderBuyerLogic + N',1'
    if (@MergeOrderTypes & 4) = 4 
        set @orderBuyerLogic = @orderBuyerLogic + N',2'
    if (@MergeOrderTypes & 8) = 8 
        set @orderBuyerLogic = @orderBuyerLogic + N',3'
    if (@MergeOrderTypes & 16) = 16 
        set @orderBuyerLogic = @orderBuyerLogic + N',4'
    if (@MergeOrderTypes & 32) = 32
        set @orderBuyerLogic = @orderBuyerLogic + N',5'
    set @orderBuyerLogic = @orderBuyerLogic + N') '
end
```

You will notice that if @OrderType is not -1 then it adds a filter that is both OrderType and @MergeOrderTypes (which is uses as a bit field.)  So if @MergeOrderType does not = 0 then you are not testing OrderType by itself.  For example if mergeordertype is 16 (or any number that has that bit set) then it will always give the 1000 records that have fgSpecialPO = 4

Thus ordertype = 4 and mergerordertype = 16 would give 1000 and ordertype = 1 and mergerordertype = 16 would give 1000.

Set mergeordertype to 0 and you will start to see things add up correctly.

ALSO if fgSpecialPO is ever null it would show up when ordertype is -1 but not when it was a value.

---

You don't say what you actually have to change logically.

In any case what you are probably not understanding is the cross join. In old style joins (and legal now too) you can have a comma on the from list and if there is nothing in the where clause that is a cross join.

Also the bad indenting.  Here is the SQL indented better with the CROSS JOIN stated in new style.

> I would be willing to bet the cross join is the bug or a bad design choice, but since you aren't telling us anything else about the model, the input, the expected output, or the source of the sql generator I can't say.

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(C.BaseOrderNo) AS [Orders Imported], 
  SUM(CASE WHEN C.TotalOrderQty = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Single Qty Orders],
  CAST(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN C.TotalOrderQty = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUMERIC) / 
                     COUNT(C.TotalOrderQty) * 100 AS DECIMAL(19,2)) AS [% Single Qty], 
  SUM(CASE WHEN C.TotalOrderQty > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Multi-Qty Orders], 
  CAST(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN C.TotalOrderQty > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUMERIC) / 
    COUNT(C.TotalOrderQty) * 100 AS DECIMAL(19,2)) AS [% Multi-Qty], 
  SUM(C.TotalOrderQty) AS [Total Qty], 
  AVG(C.TotalOrderQty) AS [Average Item Qty], 
  S.NumOrdersSplit AS [Num Orders Split], 
  CAST(CAST(S.NumOrdersSplit AS NUMERIC) / COUNT(C.BaseOrderNo)* 100 AS DECIMAL(19,2)) AS [% Split Orders], 
  SUM(CASE WHEN O.NumSplits = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [1X Split], 
  SUM(CASE WHEN O.NumSplits = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [2X Split], 
  SUM(CASE WHEN O.NumSplits = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [3X Split], 
  SUM(CASE WHEN O.NumSplits >= 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [>=4X Split] 
FROM (  
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',OA.OrderNo)>0 THEN LEFT(OA.OrderNo,CHARINDEX('-',OA.OrderNo)-1) ELSE OA.OrderNo END) AS NumOrdersSplit 
  FROM OrdersViewWImport O  WITH (NOLOCK) 
  INNER JOIN OrderActions OA WITH (NOLOCK) ON OA.OrderNo=O.OrderNo 
  left outer join VendorBuyers BORD WITH (NOLOCK)  on BORD.Buyer = 'admin' and BORD.Usage = 10000 and BORD.VendorNo = O.VendorNo and BORD.fgSpecialPO = O.fgSpecialPO 
  where 
      case when BORD.EMailId is null then case when IsNull(BORD.Type, 0) = 1 then 1 when O.fgSpecialPO in (0, 2, 4) then 1 when O.fgSpecialPO in (1, 3, 5) then 1 end else 0 end = 1 
      AND O.fgSpecialPO IN (4) AND O.ImportDate >= '2015-12-20' AND O.ImportDate < '2015-12-26' AND OA.Type=56
) S
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',OI.OrderNo)>0 THEN LEFT(OI.OrderNo,CHARINDEX('-',OI.OrderNo)-1) ELSE OI.OrderNo END AS BaseOrderNo, 
    SUM(OI.Quantity) AS TotalOrderQty, 
    COUNT(1) AS TotalLines 
  FROM OrderItems OI WITH (NOLOCK) 
  GROUP BY CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',OI.OrderNo)>0 THEN LEFT(OI.OrderNo,CHARINDEX('-',OI.OrderNo)-1) ELSE OI.OrderNo END
) C 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',O.OrderNo)>0 THEN LEFT(O.OrderNo,CHARINDEX('-',O.OrderNo)-1) ELSE O.OrderNo END AS BaseOrderNo, 
    COUNT(1) AS NumSplits, 
    O.ImportDate, 
    'Default' AS VendorNo, 
    O.fgSpecialPO 
  FROM OrdersViewWImport O WITH (NOLOCK) 
  GROUP BY 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',O.OrderNo)>0 THEN LEFT(O.OrderNo,CHARINDEX('-',O.OrderNo)-1) ELSE O.OrderNo END, 
    O.ImportDate, 
    O.fgSpecialPO
) O ON O.BaseOrderNo=C.BaseOrderNo 
inner join (
  select
    COUNT(1) as [PerOrder], 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',oa.OrderNo)>0 THEN LEFT(oa.OrderNo,CHARINDEX('-',oa.OrderNo)-1) ELSE oa.OrderNo END as BaseOrderNo 
  from OrderActions as oa WITH (NOLOCK) 
  where Type = 36  
  GROUP BY 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',oa.OrderNo)>0 THEN LEFT(oa.OrderNo,CHARINDEX('-',oa.OrderNo)-1) ELSE oa.OrderNo END
) cnt on cnt.BaseOrderNo = C.BaseOrderNo 
left outer join VendorBuyers BORD WITH (NOLOCK) on BORD.Buyer = 'admin' and BORD.Usage = 10000 and BORD.VendorNo = O.VendorNo and BORD.fgSpecialPO = O.fgSpecialPO 
where 
  case when BORD.EMailId is null then case when IsNull(BORD.Type, 0) = 1 then 1 when O.fgSpecialPO in (0, 2, 4) then 1 when O.fgSpecialPO in (1, 3, 5) then 1 end else 0 end = 1 
  AND O.fgSpecialPO IN (4) 
  AND O.ImportDate >= '2015-12-20' 
  AND O.ImportDate < '2015-12-26' 
GROUP BY S.NumOrdersSplit 
ORDER BY [Orders Imported]
```

Comment: yea, depending on any of 9 parameters, this SQL gets built conditionally. If I posted the actual SP, it would only make things worse. This SP has a lot of permutations as it'll make any of X reports depending on params. Poorly thought out, IMO.

Comment: but that explanation you gave helped! Not sure if it's 'the answer' yet, but if it solves my problem I'll come back and mark it so.

Comment: I edited my original post and added the full SP. The semantic error is harder to explain but I''ll add that to the post too